# Python 3.5.2 : How to transform cookie's format into dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am using Python 3.5.2 and Scrapy 1.1 .
In browser,cookie is like this:

```
currency=USD;country=UY
```

I want it to be a dictionary,like this:

```
cookie={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'}
```

Which function should I use?

Comment: if you are getting a whole string of cookie then you can split using two different delimiters and then store it in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back and I came to terms that there is no pretty way to do this. I just chopped up a solution that worked:

```
cookie_string="currency=USD;country=UY"
cookie_string_field=cookie_string.split(";")
cookie_dict={}
for cookie in cookie_string_field:
    cookie_dict[cookie.split("=")[0]]=cookie.split("=")[1]
print cookie_dict
```

This solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import http.cookies

c = http.cookies.SimpleCookie()
c.load('currency=USD;country=UY')

data = {key: c[key].value for key in c}

print(data) # {'country': 'UY', 'currency': 'USD'}
```